# How to create this grid-based layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I create the layout? I am new to Android.

[image]

Comment: its easy to design... try it inside a vertical linear layout....

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Welcome to the Cup Management System"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="Enter The Current Year"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="Enter The Admin Code"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="Enter The Admin Code Again"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="Enter admin's e-mail to send reports to"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="Enter(again) admin's e-mail to send reports to"
                android:textSize="18sp" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:text="Let's Go!"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```